# What are the Differences between XSLT and the T4 Code Generation Methods?

Tags: .net, xslt, code-generation, t4

I am just getting into the idea of code generation for repetitive coding tasks and have seen both of these approaches. I've seen the XSLT approach in an Apress book [Code Generation in Microsoft .Net](http://apress.com/book/view/1590591372/) and have read about the T4 approach in relation to what's new in the MVC framework.

What kind of projects is each method better suited for? A quick glance tells me that T4 is a more lightweight system, is that true?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well yes - T4 is a template-based approach that can pull information from a variety of sources - typically from a database (table or system catalogs).

T4 is built into VS 2008 - you can define a .tt file inside VS2008 and have it generate its output inside VS.

XSLT has one requirement - input must be XML, and XSLT itself also is XML, so there's a number of challenges and possible drawbacks there.

XSLT is stand-alone - you can install and use any number of XSL engines.

All in all: T4 to me is more of a "inside VS" code-generation tool (to quickly create C# or other files), while XSLT is more of a data-processing/data-transformation tool to turn data from XML into another format (typically HTML or PDF using XSL-FO).

Marc